# Does Windows Phone 8 implies NFC tag support?

Tags: nfc

Does every `Windows Phone 8` device has support for `NFC` tag(the `NFC` chipset)? Are there any `Windows 7.8 or lower` devices that support `NFC` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does every Windows Phone 8 device has support for NFC tag(the NFC chipset)?

[The minimum hardware requirements for a phone to be acceptable as a **Windows Phone 8** device as set by Microsoft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8#Hardware_requirements):

> - Qualcomm Snapdragon S4 dual-core processor or Snapdragon 800
> - Minimum 512 MB RAM for WVGA phones; minimum 1 GB RAM for 720p / WXGA / 1080p
> - Minimum 4 GB flash memory
> - GPS and A-GNSS; GLONASS is supported if OEMs decide to include it
> - Support for micro-USB 2.0
> - 3.5 mm stereo headphone jack with three-button detection support
> - Rear-facing AF camera with optional LED or Xenon flash, optional front-facing camera (both need to be VGA or better) and dedicated camera button
> - Accelerometer, proximity and ambient light sensors, as well as vibration motor (magnetometer and gyroscope are optional)
> - 802.11b/g and Bluetooth (802.11n is optional)
> - DirectX graphics hardware support with hardware acceleration for Direct3D using programmable GPU
> - Multi-touch capacitive touch screen with minimum of four simultaneous points

**Hence, it is not necessary for every Windows Phone 8 device to have NFC.**

> Are there any Windows 7.8 or lower devices that support NFC tags?

[**This list of all Windows Phone 7.x devices**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Windows_Phone_7_devices) can be cross-referenced with [**this list of all NFC-enabled devices** to find the subset you are looking for.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NFC-enabled_mobile_devices)

Answer (score 1):

No, not all Windows Phone 8 devices have NFC but you'll find it's only missing on the lowest end devices for cost reasons, [such as the Nokia Lumia 520](http://www.nokia.com/us-en/phones/phone/lumia520/#ProductSpecsWidget).

Windows Phone 7 has no support for NFC with one exception, [which is the Lumia 610](http://venturebeat.com/2012/04/11/nokia-lumia-610-nfc/). As no platform support was provided for developers, NFC functionality on this phone was very limited and no app could support or extend it - unlike on Windows Phone 8.